# Do I need to map skeletal data into color image point? - kinect/XNA

Tags: kinect, xna-4.0

I have been working on a project where I need to interact with 3D objects using a hand joint, now I do that using distance formula but however . . i'm using hand joint (X,Y,Z) and using a formula to convert them to 3D space to be able to have the interact with the Models.

Instead of using a formula to do the conversion . . do i actually need to use the function MapSkeletalpoint to color image point??

To give an idea about what i'm doing:

```
         var rightHands = playerSkeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
         var rightHandsX = rightHands.Position.X;
         var rightHandsY = rightHands.Position.Y;
         var rightHandsZ = rightHands.Position.Z;


          HandX = rightHands.Position.X;
          HandY = rightHands.Position.Y;
          HandZ = rightHands.Position.Z;

    foreach (_3DModel s in Solar)
    {
         x_mod = (float)Math.Floor(((HandX * 0.5f)) * maxWidth);
         y_mod = (float)Math.Floor(((HandY * -0.5f)) * maxHeight);
         z_mod = (float)Math.Floor((HandZ) / 4 * 20000);



  if (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x_mod - s.modelPosition.X, 2) + Math.Pow(y_mod- s.modelPosition.Y, 2) + Math.Pow(z_mod - s.modelPosition.Z,2)) < 20)
     {

          sound.Play();
         Console.WriteLine("1" + "handx:" + x + "," + " " + "modelPos.X:" + s.modelPosition.X + "," + " " + "handY:" + y + "modelPos.Y:" + s.modelPosition.Y);
     }
```

Comment: If you map to Color, it will convert into RGB image space (eg: 2d), so that won't really apply to your use case, since you want a 3d hit test.

Comment: Exactly.. So is there anyway apart from the conversions i'm currently using to make it work with 3D coordinate space?

Comment: There's different type of formulas you can apply to your point, you could also use 3d transformations, that's mostly the same concept.

Comment: Could you please give an example or so.. cos the one i'm using is error bound and wont work for certain model positions

Comment: It will depend on how your models are organized, but for a fast hit test, first you should make sure all of your models have a bounding volume (box or sphere). Hit test from there is very simple and fast. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not easy to create effective hit test especially when there is larger number of objects.

The thing you need is a collision system. My recommendation to you is that you should use some existing, for example BEPU might be helpful:
http://bepu.squarespace.com/

You should bind the position of an object with the position of the hand (reported by Kinect) and BEPU will do the rest (it will trigger a handler in case of collision).

Just a small advice - it's always good to use relative position of the hand (e.g. to the shoulder). Using absolute coordinates reported by Kinect is not always desired in Kinect-based games (but you know better what you want)